# FileUploadBasic does not call onProgress function

Tags: javascript, ajax-upload

I've downloaded the following plugin: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ and am using the basic FileUploaderBasic version. The problem is the onProgres function never gets called. Do I need to adapt my serverside code for this?

```
 var uploader = new qq.FileUploaderBasic({
    button: uploadButton,
    action: url,
    debug: true,
    onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total){
                var percentLoaded = (loaded / total) * 100;
                $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
                    value: percentLoaded
                });
            },
    onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        alert('done!');
    }                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the server blocks Third party srcipts like http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ ..for bypassing this you need to add these lines to your .htacess file.The same problem occurred for me also.I bypassed it using these codes

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Hope this will works